# Linker Errors LNK2019 and LNK1120 in single file code

Tags: c++, lnk2019

[C++ code of my compiler](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8sttmrp2ekjq4l/azaab.cpp?dl=0)
There is only one .cpp file in my Win32 console project. I am facing these LNK compile-time errors in my code. I am working on Visual Studio 12. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to have solved my issue.

I am writing code for a compiler that was originally built in Java and now the task at hand is to convert it in C++. I am looking forward to some useful solutions.
Can anyone help me with this task?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You really need to copy and paste the text of the actual error messages so that we can see exactly what it says.

Comment: Here is the documentation page for LNK2019 and LNK1120: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z98k84c3.aspx

Comment: There are lots of errors.  1) main doesn't return void 2) you haven't defined lex() anywhere 3) `out_parser<"error not occured\n";` and `out_parser<"error occured\n";` aren't valid (it should be `<<`)

Comment: I have update the question and attached a screenshot of error @JerryJeremiah

Comment: I did not find the solution to my specific problem in already posted questions. They are related to multiple files where there are dependencies issues etc. My code only has one file so there shouldn't be any link error. I am confused

Comment: I need help removing this error as I have to submit this project in a few hours. I'll be thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019):

> unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'
>
> The compiled code for function makes a reference or call to symbol,
> but that symbol isn't defined in any of the libraries or object files
> specified to the linker.
>
> This error message is followed by fatal error
> LNK1120. You must fix all LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors to fix error
> LNK1120.

You are referencing something not in the file that you are not linking to.

Answer (score 1):

The specific error in the screenshot says that the `string terminalEP(void)` function being called from the terminalP function does not exist - and it is true because your terminalEP function is definaed as `string terminalEP(string str)` but the line that calls it from the terminalP function is `s=terminalEP();`

You need to pass a parameter to the terminalEP function or you need to make the parameter for the terminalEP function have a default value.